# AspectJ not weaving on test-compile but weaves on compile. Therefore unit tests throw ClassNotFoundException when running with maven

Tags: java, maven, junit, aspectj

All my junit tests have been passing in eclipse, but when run from the console they seem to throw ClassNotFoundException for the AJ class RiskLogAspect.aj I can verify that in eclipse this is correctly weaving and providing the required functionality.

I've tried adding dependencies to my project to make sure there all correct.

I started adding the aspectj-maven-plugin

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>compile</goal>
                    <goal>test-compile</goal>
                </goals>
            <phase>process-sources</phase>
                <configuration>
                    <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
                    <encoding>UTF8</encoding>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <aspects>
                        <includes>
                            <include>com.idna.riskprofile.RiskLogAspect</include>
                        </includes>
                    </aspects>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

I then added the following dependencies

```
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
      <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.7</version>
    </dependency>
```

Any ideas what's going wrong ?

I'm running maven 2.0.9 and also jdK 1.6 update 21

After changing some of my configuration I've noticed in the console I get the follow "  [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch] " It seems like it is picking up my class but not applying the pointcut correctly.

For the goal compile it finds the AJ file and applies the advice correctly, for the test-compile goal it says Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch and throws class not found exceptions for half the junit tests.
From the console:

```
[INFO] [aspectj:compile {execution: default}]
[INFO] Join point 'method-execution(java.lang.String com.idna.riskprofile.impl.RiskProfileEntryPointImpl.execute(com.idna.riskprofile.domain.RiskProfileRequest))' in Type 'com.idna.riskprofile.impl.RiskProfileEntryPointImpl' (RiskProfileEntryPointImpl.java:35) advised by around advice from 'com.idna.riskprofile.logging.aspects.RiskLogAspect' (RiskLogAspect.aj:35)
[INFO] [aspectj:test-compile {execution: default}]
[WARNING] advice defined in com.idna.riskprofile.logging.aspects.RiskLogAspect has not been applied [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch]
[INFO] [resources:resources]
```

Updated: It seems that not weaving advice on the test-compile goal was not what was leading to the test failures on the console but another issue with spring configuration.

Comment: when you say the top level package - do you mean the source package or a parent maven module. Could you may post the whole pom or at least relevant portions

Comment: Did you Maven...Update Project Configuration in Eclipse?

Comment: I have tried the update project config. Also the package was com.myproject.somepackage.X and everything sat below somepackage so I removed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Registering the aspectj plugin isn't enough, you need to register some goals as well:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
                <!-- use this goal to weave all your main classes -->
                <goal>test-compile</goal>
                <!-- use this goal to weave all your test classes -->
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Okay I tried this. Makes no difference. I originally was getting a lot of issues indicating I needed to be on JDK 1.5 or above (I'm using 1.6) so I added config to the goals to use 1.6. End up at the same place I started. Tests pass in eclipse but not on the console.